# What is the mobius function for the set of simplicial complexes on n vertices?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics

Consider the set of simplicial complexes on $n$ vertices, with partial ordering by containment. What is the Mobius function for this poset?

Are other combinatorial facts known about it (e.g. the number of chains of a given length from one simplicial complex to another)?

Comment: Isn't it $0$ if to get from the larger to the smaller you have to remove any simplex that is a face of another simplex, and $(-1)$ to the number of simplices removed otherwise?

Comment: @WillSawin: I think I agree on the second case, $(-1)$ to the number of simplices removed if the removed simplices are all incomparable to one another (by comparison to a powerset or boolean algebra), but how does the 0 show up?

Comment: Same way it does in the divisibility poset of the natural numbers for non-squarefree numbers.